# Verification Required during inApp purchase

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

While testing my inApp purchase I keep getting this message. I have verified my test account online with appleid.apple.com. I also downloaded some apps to make sure its working.

I went through this blog http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ with no luck.

The related post [iOS in-app purchases sandbox environment - verification required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240543/ios-in-app-purchases-sandbox-environment-verification-required) did not have an answer yet.

Please help, this is driving me MAD

[image: Verification Required Image]